# Visual Studio 2005 stopped adding code-behind files

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2005, code-behind

This morning, when I tried to add a new ASPX page to my project, Visual Studio decided that I no longer needed any .CS files associated with it. Trying to add a web control produced same results: .ascx file with no .cs. I've got two questions so far:

1. Considering that no changes have been made to the system over the weekend, what could be the cause of this?
2. Is re-installing VS the only option right now?

I'm running Visual Studio 2005 SP1 on Windows XP SP3.

Thanks!

EDIT: Thank you all. The checkbox DID get unchecked at some point and I simply did not see it. I will blame this one on Monday...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a check box you may have accidentaly un-checked: Place code in separate file
[image: dialog]
<sub>(source: [msdn.com](http://blogs.msdn.com/blogfiles/mikeormond/WindowsLiveWriter/NewWebItemTemplatesinVisualStudioOrcasBe_CC5B/image%5B9%5D.png))</sub>

Answer (score 1):

That can be considered a feature by the ASP.NET MVC folks.

Comment: Right! So what's the problem again?

Answer (score 1):

Usually, there is a check box asking if you want to have the code in a separate file.  Did this box get unchecked at some point (and so it's now the default)?  It's easy to get in the habit of clicking through these common dialogs and not noticing that it may have changed.

Answer (score 1):

I don't mean to be rude by asking an obvious question, but have you made sure that the "place code in a separate file" check box is checked when you create your page?